# Eclipse can't see /usr/local folder on mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, tomcat, finder

I am developing a web application in Java on my mac.
The web application will run on tomcat.
I have installed tomcat in `/usr/local/apache-tomcat`.

When I try to set the tomcat runtime in `Server->Runtime Environments`, I am not able to see the folder `/usr/local`. **how do I get eclipse to see the `/usr/local/apache-tomcat` directory?**

I am able to see `/usr/local` when using the `Go to Folder` option in Finder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with loading external jar files in /usr/local/ for Eclipse on Mac
  The way i resolved this was to create a soft-link using ln -s to the folder in /usr/local to a visible folder and then loaded the jars.

```
ln -s source visible_location/link
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just got a similar problem, and the workaround i found is to **copy/paste** the *path* of your *tomcat base* directory, and it works fine:

1. Go to your **tomcat base** directory
2. `pwd` to get the path and copy it
3. Go to eclipse -> preferences -> servers -> runtime environments -> add button -> select apache tomcat version -> then next
4. At this step, instead of browsing, you can simply paste the copied path in the *Tomcat installation directory* field!

[image]

et voilà

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have your finder settings that hide hidden folders.  It is possible to show them by [following the instructions in this article](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/04/show-hidden-files.html).

The easiest way to do this is to type the following in your terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

If you type out the full name of the installation folder instead of using the finder, does it work?

Comment: I have done this, but I still can't see the folder from within eclipse. If you see the image I have provided, I have chosen 'Macintosh HD', so I should be able to see the /usr/local folder, but I don't see it.

Comment: Hard to say what's happening here. Try this:  Go to your finder (outside of eclipse), navigate to the `/usr` folder and then drag the `local` folder to the left hand side where the _favorites_ are. Then try opening again in Eclipse. You _should_ now see the `/usr/local` folder as an option.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewEisenberg. Adding the folder to favorites solves it for me

Answer (score 0):

You can easily control hidden files writing this in bash_profile

```
alias hideOn='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE'
alias hideOff='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE'
alias kFinder='killAll Finder'
alias hOn='hideOn && kFinder'
alias hOff='hideOff && kFinder'
```

Then, reopen your terminal and write hOn. At root folder you will see hidden /usr. Just put it in your finder sidebar. Then write hOff and you will stop seeing the hidden files, but /usr will be always there at finder.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to choose the folder, press 'Cmd + Shift + G' in the dialog box.  This brings up a prompt where you can enter the path